# How to generate a date range + count earlier dates from another table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, count, range

I have the following table:

`links`:

```
created_at           active 
2017-08-12 15:46:01  false
2017-08-13 15:46:01  true
2017-08-14 15:46:01  true
2017-08-15 15:46:01  false
```

When given a date range, I have to extract time series which tells me how many active links were created on a date equal or smaller than current (rolling) date.

Output (for date range 2017-08-12 - 2017-08-17):

```
day          count
2017-08-12   0 (there are 0 active links created on 2017-08-12 and earlier)
2017-08-13   1 (there is 1 active link created on 2017-08-13 and earlier)
2017-08-14   2 (there are 2 active links created on 2017-08-14 and earlier)
2017-08-15   2 ...
2017-08-16   2
2017-08-17   2
```

I came up with the following query for generating dates:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', dd):: date
FROM generate_series
    ( '2017-08-12'::timestamp 
    , '2017-08-17'::timestamp
    , '1 day'::interval) dd
```

But the rolling counts confuse me and am unsure how to continue. Can this be solved with a window function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fastest:

```
SELECT day::date
     , sum(ct) OVER (ORDER BY day) AS count
FROM   generate_series (timestamp '2017-08-12'
                      , timestamp '2017-08-17'
                      , interval  '1 day') day
LEFT   JOIN  (
   SELECT date_trunc('day', created_at) AS day, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  active -- fastest
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t USING (day)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=789f500cdd8e6304b5f5c41296874a27)*

`count()` only counts non-null rows, so you could use `count(active OR NULL)`. But the fastest option for counting is to exclude irrelevant rows with a `WHERE` clause to begin with. Since we are adding all days with `generate_series()` anyway, this is the best option.

Compare:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count)

Since `generate_series()` returns `timestamp` (not `date`) I use `date_trunc()` to get matching timestamps (very slightly faster).

Answer (score 1):

I would just use aggregation and cumulative sums -- assuming you have at least one per day:

```
select date_trunc('day', created_at)::date as created_date,
       sum(active::int) as actives,
       sum(sum(active::int)) over (date_trunc('day', created_at)) as running_actives
from t
group by created_date;
```

You only need to generate the dates if you have holes in the data.  If you do, though, I would recommend including `where active` -- you can include it now, I just want to be sure there are no holes.

Comment: Yes, there are holes, some days are missing. So for those days I have to take the count for the most recent previous date that exists.

Answer (score 1):

**Demo**

http://rextester.com/OGZV44492

**SQL**

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', dd):: date AS day,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM links
        WHERE active = true
          AND date(created_at) <= date_trunc('day', dd)) AS "count"
FROM generate_series
    ( '2017-08-12'::timestamp 
    , '2017-08-17'::timestamp
    , '1 day'::interval) dd
```

**Explanation**

The SQL above does a simple subselect to count the number of rows in the `links` table whose date part is less than or equal to each date in the generated range.

Comment: I really like this one! Thanks Steve.

Comment: I realized this query doesn't scale well for a very large table, so I selected Erwin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think a query like this can help you:

```
;with t as (SELECT date_trunc('day', dd):: date
FROM generate_series
    ( '2017-08-12'::timestamp 
    , '2017-08-17'::timestamp
    , '1 day'::interval) dd
)
select distinct t.date_trunc
  , count(case when links.active = 'true' then 1 end) over (order by links.created_at) count
from t
left join links
on t.date_trunc = cast(links.created_at as date)
order by t.date_trunc;
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/450cf/3)**

Answer (score 0):

If you have missing days in your table, you'll need to use a generate_series() to create them. Since this is basically putting together the two previous answers, credit is given ;;)

However, this join is better done after the GROUP BY, which will only return one row per day, instead of before, which would result in a larger JOIN.

```
WITH dailydata AS (
  SELECT 
    d::DATE, COALESCE(n,0) n
  FROM
    generate_series( 
      '2000-01-01'::DATE, 
      '2000-10-01'::DATE,
      '1 DAY'::INTERVAL ) d
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT created_at::DATE d, count(*) AS n
    FROM links WHERE active
    GROUP BY d) data
    USING (d)
)
SELECT d, n, sum(n) OVER (ORDER BY d) FROM dailydata;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE links
        ( created_at           timestamp
        , active boolean
        );
INSERT INTO links(created_at,active)VALUES
 ('2017-08-12 15:46:01', false)
,('2017-08-13 15:46:01', true)
,('2017-08-14 15:46:01', true)
,('2017-08-15 15:46:01', false)
        ;
```

---

```
WITH cal AS (
        select gs AS deet
        FROM generate_series('2017-08-11'::date,'2017-08-16'::date, '1day'::interval)gs
        )
SELECT cal.deet
        , SUM(1) FILTER (WHERE l.active =True) OVER(ORDER BY l.created_at) AS cumsum
FROM cal
LEFT JOIN links l ON date_trunc('days', l.created_at)= cal.deet
ORDER BY created_at
        ;
```